# vector field: changing vector magnitudes to make it conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Consider a vector field $$\vec{F}(x,y)=P(x,y)\vec{i}+Q(x,y)\vec{j}$$  on an open and simply-connected region. Assume $P$ and $Q$ have continuous partial derivatives.
Under which conditions there exists a positive-valued function $\mu (x,y)$ such that $$\mu\vec{F}(x,y)=\mu(x,y)P(x,y)\vec{i}+\mu(x,y)Q(x,y)\vec{j}$$ is a conservative vector field?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, you could start by applying any conditions that you might know of for a vector field to be conservative to $\mu\vec F$.

Comment: What about $\mu(x,y)=0$? (Yes, I know it is a "silly" objection, most likely that's not what you meant. But then you have to be clear about exactly what requirements you have on $\mu$.)

Comment: First, thanks for the editing! Second, I would like $μ(x,y)>0$... The idea is that it should preserve the directions in the vector field. I apologize for my poor math knowledge.

Comment: To amd. For the field $\mu F$ to be conservative, I would need that
$$
\mu _y P + \mu P_y = \mu _x Q + \mu Q_x
$$
which remains difficult for me to investigate! Is the answer trivial?